# How to move a plist from the bundle to the documents folder on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So all I want to know is how to move a plist from the bundle to the documents folder the first time an application runs, because I need it. Please I can't find out how to do it, so help me.

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830061/copy-folder-w-contents-from-bundle-to-documents-directory-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your plist name is "friends"

just use below code ( it will find whether the file exists or not and copies)

```
NSFileManager *fileManger=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString *doumentDirectoryPath=[pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *destinationPath= [doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"friends.plist"];

NSLog(@"plist path %@",destinationPath);    
if ([fileManger fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]){
    //NSLog(@"database localtion %@",destinationPath);
    return;
}
NSString *sourcePath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"friends.plist:];

[fileManger copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];
```

that will copy plist from resources to documents directory

Answer (score 2):

This function should do the trick.

```
- (void)copyPlist {
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myplist" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:plistPath toPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
}
```

You don't *need* to use the NSError argument in the `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:plistPath toPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];` line, but it may be useful for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up... this came from http://samsoff.es/posts/iphone-plist-tutorial "Using JSON is highly preferred over Plists these days since JSON parsers have come a long way in speed. They are actually faster than binary plists now (which is nuts). Anyway, please, please, please don't use plists for your API. Generating them is slow and unreliable. You should use JSON. Period."

Comment: What if convenience is more important than speed? What if using the Xcode built-in tools is just more fun and reliable than manually editing a JSON file? What if the type-safety of a plist is an important factor?

Comment: I don't believe that post. BINARY plists are more compact than an ASCII based format like JASON, so they transmit faster over the network. They store values in binary format, so they don't need to be converted from strings into bools/floats/integers, etc. The don't use characters as delimiters, etc, etc. I saw a presentation from a senior developer I respect a lot who compared plists, JSON, and XML. JSON was somewhat faster to parse than XML, and required less memory, but binary plists were at least 10X faster than both. That was about a year ago, after this bogus post was made.

Comment: Ahh very interesting Duncan. Would like to see a link to that presentation if possible! Also, Till, I was quoting another's work. Your comment seems a bit childish.