# How to put images into a folder & get them from documents directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager, nsbundle, nsdocumentdirectory

In my app there are multiple images in different folders (5 altogether). How can i put these folders into the document directory?

Then how do I to get the count and the images' name from a particular images folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Working_with_Directories](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_on_iOS_4_%28iPhone%29) link.

**EDIT** : `Copy` `item` refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830585/1106035) link

Refer [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details:

Comment: i already have five folder with multiple images. How can i put these folder to Document directory (without programing if possible)? than i want the count and filename of particular images .

Comment: i just want to tell you that i have folders in my project .than how can i access that ? dont have knowledge about document directory so not getting your ans ..

Comment: if u have folders in application ie its from main bundle. Also document directory is to store your data after application becomes active(used). U can copy bundle items into document directory for structured layout in different folders. But u cannot do nothing in main bundle

Comment: yes exactly . so tell me how can i copy my bundle (images with folder) to document directory. are bhai e j to question hato maro ..

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830061/copy-folder-w-contents-from-bundle-to-documents-directory-ios/9830585#9830585 to copy item. bhai kene tare su joye che

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *dimage = [UIImage imagedNamed:@"yourImage.png"]; //get the image name here
 NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString *imageName = @"myImageName.png";
 NSArray *patharr=[ImagePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
 NSString* Ext=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[patharr objectAtIndex:1]];
 NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDir,ImagePath]];


 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(dimage)];
 [data writeToFile:FilePath atomically:YES];
```

> Further getting the contents of documents directory's filenames...

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString *dir in dirContents) {
        if ([dir hasSuffix:@".png"]) {
            NSRange range = [dir rangeOfString:@"."];
            NSString *name = [dir substringToIndex:range.location];
            if (![name isEqualToString:@""]) {

                [array addObject:name];
            }
        }
    } 
NSLog(@"document folder content list %@ ",array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the images from your directory

```
array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"folderName"];
```

Comment: in my project i have one images>emotions . i have tried but not working . how can i give the path ?

Comment: you need to put your last directory folder and set the type it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

 Path for document directory and store image

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

if let image = UIImage(named: "example.png") {
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation() {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
        try? data.write(to: filename)
    }
}
```